# Inject env variable into build stage of image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

Working on a CI/CD pipeline for a Django based API. I need to inject an environmental variable during the build stage to successfully build the image.

- `python manage.py collectstatic` is run in the `Dockerfile` when the image is being built
- `collectstatic` needs the `SECRET_KEY` in the `settings.py` to run
- `SECRET_KEY` is empty during this stage because it is read in with `os.environ['SECRET_KEY]`
- Because it is empty, the build fails
- Thus, I need to set the environment to have this variable

I am having trouble putting that much together, so wanted to see if anyone could assist me.

This is what I have so far:

**Azure Pipeline**

[image]

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  secretKey: $(SECRET_KEY)

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - bash:
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: $(secretKey)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push api image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)-api
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/api/Dockerfile
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN python manage.py collectstatic
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

**Build fail log** (probably not helpful because I know why it failed... `SECRET_KEY` isn't in env vars)

```
Step 8/18 : RUN python manage.py collectstatic
 ---> Running in 1f42a5c062aa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/config/settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py collectstatic' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py collectstatic' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

I'm just not sure how to accomplish getting the environmental variable in there. My approach could be totally wrong from the beginning.

So how should I go about:

1. Declaring the environmental variables in the pipeline securely?
2. Passing said environmental variables into the build stage?

Thanks!

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Well, I was hoping there was a way to do this with the `azure-pipelines.yml` and Azure DevOps Pipelines. Option 1. provided below was what I Had in mind if this was not doable.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Would `arguments: --secret` be the means of handling this in the `azure-pipelines.yml`? Are there security issues related to it with the secrets embedded in the image?

Comment: Meant to include link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#other-commands-and-arguments

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Is this just not doable with Variables in Azure Pipelines and in the `azure-pipelines.yml`? Messed with it several more hours and no luck.

Comment: Please view Levi's answer below.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to have a dummy-key for the build-phase: `RUN SECRET_KEY=dummy django-admin collectstatic`?

Comment: @mandrake It would. There's a production example in https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/main/Dockerfile. But if you use `os.environ['YOUR_KEY']` (without the fallback) I believe `collectstatic` will throw on every such env var access occassion. If you have multiple variables it can quickly become ugly. But its' doable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `python manage.py collectstatic` is running in the docker container, and its `os.environ['SECRET_KEY]` will try to get the environment variable of the container where it is running. But the environment variable SECRET_KEY you were setting in your pipeline is for build agent.

You can try following below steps to pass your pipeline env variable to the docker container.

1, I add an `ARG` and an `ENV` in your dockerfile `ARG SECRET; ENV SECRET_KEY $SECRET`

`ENV SECRET_KEY` refers to the value of `ARG SECRET`

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ARG SECRET
ENV SECRET_KEY $SECRET

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN python manage.py collectstatic
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

2, I separate docker buildandpush task to dock build and dock push, as buildandpush command cannot accept arguments.

In docker **build** task. I passed the variable `secretKey` to the **arguments** field `--build-arg SECRET=$(secretKey)`. So that when docker run build, `ARG SECRET` will be replaced by `secretKey`. And it will be passed to the `ENV SECRET_KEY` as defined in above dockerfile. So that SECRET_KEY will be set to the docker container's Environment variable.

Then you python code should be able to get the environment variable's value using `os.environ['SECRET_KEY]`

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: $(imageRepository)-api
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/api/Dockerfile
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

        arguments: --build-arg SECRET=$(secretKey)

        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push
      inputs:
        command: push
        repository: $(imageRepository)-api
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)


- upload: manifests
  artifact: manifests
```

Comment: This does work! However, the problem I'm running into now is security. While doing something like `RUN echo ${SECRET_KEY}` doesn't print out the value, when I pull the image and run `docker history <image id>` it does print out a portion of the `SECRET_KEY`. Instead of using `arguments: --build-arg:`, I tried to use `arguments: --secret`, but the values do not get passed into the Dockerfile. Is there a more secure way than using `--build-arg`?

Comment: If you want to use docker secrets, You might need to use docker compose and set the secret to env variable for your container. You can refer to [this example](https://medium.com/@adrian.gheorghe.dev/using-docker-secrets-in-your-environment-variables-7a0609659aab). You can aslo use a powershell task to execute your docker command in your docker file in pure powershell commands, and set your pipelince secret to the env variable for your container using powershell script.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you

Comment: THIS IS SECURITY LEAK !!! NEVER SHARE IMAGE BUILD LIKE THIS !!!

`docker history --no-trunc --format "{{.CreatedBy}}" IMAGE_NAME`

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this securely in Docker 18.09+ is to use [Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) and [secrets](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information).

Modify your pipeline as follows:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1

steps:
  - bash: |
      echo ${SECRET_KEY} > ${PIPELINE_WORKSPACE}/secret_key.txt
    displayName: Store secret
    env:
      SECRET_KEY: $(secretKey)

  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      command: build
      arguments: --secret id=secret_key,src=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/secret_key.txt
```

And in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=secret_key \
  export SECRET_KEY=$(cat /run/secrets/secret_key) && \
  python manage.py collectstatic
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject env variables using `--build-arg` and corresponding `ARG` command in `Dockerfile`, but this is *not secure*. The key will become embedded in the image!

Your options if you want to be secure:

1. Download whatever stuff you need to using the secret key *outside* of Docker build, and just copy that in.
2. Use the (experimental, but less buggy than in the past) BuildKit backend for Docker, which supports passing in secrets securely.
3. Run a network server in another container, run your Docker build with `--network container:<thatcontainerid>` and now you can send queries to that other container to get the secrets. Or similarly run webserver on host, do `--network host`.

Longer writeup, which also mentions some other alternatives, like copying via multi-stage build: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/