# How do I add environment variables to a container with azure build yml?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

Trying to deploy an app to kubernetes using azure. I have a build pipeline yml file and in the pipeline i've set a variable called "discordToken". I tried setting it two different ways, one is called discordToken and the other is MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR. 
in my node project i'm doing

```
console.log( process.env.discordToken )
console.log( process.env.MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR )
```

but everything keeps coming back as undefined.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      environment:
        discordToken: $(discordToken)
    steps:
    - powershell: |
      env:
        MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(discordToken)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

How should i be setting the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you directly set the environment variable (env:xxx) in Powershell Task, the variable can only be used by the current task.

You could try to [set the variables with script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts), then the variables could be used by following task.

For example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR]$(discordToken)"
```

You could set the reference variable in **Settings -> Variables**:

[image: Variables]

Here is a ticket about [set environment variables in dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784488/13464420), it may help you.