# How to set environment variables (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT) in AzureDevops for Dockerfile?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I was planning to use Azure Devops to do the CI/CD for my dockerized .NET Core API.
My API now have `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.

Below are my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

As can seen, I set the environment at `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and also the `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll", "--environment=Development"]`. However how can I make it flexible in Azure Devops pipeline?

For example having different environments like `development` and `production`. So let say I have another `appsettings.Production.json`, the project would automatically pick up this file instead of `appsettings.Development.json` if I set the environment to `Production`.

Is there anyway to do this or am I understanding this whole flow wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: along with ENTRYPOINT you use CMD. you place this one `"--environment=Development"` in CMD. CMD works like a default placeholder if nothing is passed, else whatever will be passed.

Comment: Have you seen this Article [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Docker/ASPNET-Core-and-Docker-Environment-Variables)? There everything is described very well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer in this case: [Inject env variable into build stage of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690017/inject-env-variable-into-build-stage-of-image/59784488#59784488)

You can set an `ARG var_name` and reference ENV to the ARG variables. Then you can replace those variables when docker build the image `$ docker build --build-arg var_name=$(VARIABLE_NAME)`

For example the add ARG in dockerfile, and have the ENV variable refer to it:

```
ARG SECRET
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$SECRET
```

You can use dock build task and dock push task separately, as buildandpush command cannot accept arguments. And set a variable `SECRET` in your pipeline.

[image]

The set the Build Arguments `SECRET= $(SECRET)` to replace the ARG SECRET

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?