# How to embed environment variables in a docker image in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-devops

My requirement is to set few environment variables on the docker image that is built by azure devops pipeline.

This pipeline is used for dev/stage/production environments, each stage is tied to its own set of group variables, these variables I want to be available in nodejs app.

I can read the variables within the pipeline using $VARNAME but cant read same when the code runs using process.env.VARNAME.

I understand that it is not the best approach as the image would have environment variables which may potentially have secrets hence I am open to different ideas as well.

What I have tried so far:
Added ARG in dockerfile
ARG VARNAME=somevalue
on the docker build task added

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build docker image
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: $(imageName)
    tags: $(Build.BuildId)        
    buildContext: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/PublishedWebApp'
    arguments: --build-arg SOMEVAR=anewvalue
```

I try to access this as process.env.SOMEVAR in nodejs code.

I can actually see the --build-arg on the docker build executed in the pipeline but in the code it never appears.

What I am after is pretty standard requirement, we have multiple environments, each environment will have different keys (different group variables tied to different stage), how do I pass different keys to the deployment?

Comment: iirc when you use the predefined Azure Devops Docker task, you can submit build args on a docker build task `--build-arg STAGE=$(VAR_STAGE)"` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops - but then you cannot use the `build_and_push` task but you have to split the build and the push part

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I tried arguments: --build-arg varname=whatever but this also doesnt reflect with in the code. process.env.varname comens as undefined. I had a look here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ it says that it sets it for the build time, does that mean it wouldnt be available later the app would run?

Comment: ah I reckon I need to put that as ARG in docker file first, trying that

Comment: even after adding ARG, it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

There are a few components from what I can see that need to align:

1. You are passing the key via `--build-arg`. This is correct.
2. You have an `ARG` in the dockerfile to receive what is passed in via `--build-arg`. This is correct.
3. You are missing setting the environment variable equal to the passed-in arg.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ARG SOME_PASSED_IN_ARG
ENV SOMEVARNAME $SOME_PASSED_IN_ARG
...
```

You would access `SOMEVARNAME` like `process.env.SOMEVARNAME` from the node application.

I give credit to @levi-lu-msft in their post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784488/1490277

As for best practice, defining logic default environment variables in the container at BUILD is perfectly acceptable (e.g. ENV=PRODUCTION). At RUN, you are able to to overwrite any environment variable using passed in arguments:

`docker run ... --e SOME_PASSED_IN_ARG=someOtherValue`

A few "better" practices:

1. Containers are meant to be repeatable. Don't embed at BUILD time environment variable that will expire/change over time. In other words, if you decide to deploy a version from 3yrs ago and a BUILD time environment variable has an expired value (e.g. coupon code), your environment could be fragile and unpredictable.
2. Never embed secrets in the container at BUILD. #1 above because they may change overtime and also for security. Secret values (e.g., one-time keys, tokens, etc.) are available to anyone (bad actor or mishap actor) to extract simply by listing the environment variables of the image when running.